# Part of code not initialized

Tags: java, initialization

I have been in the process of re-learning Java in the last few days and have had no issues at to this point till now. I am trying to write a chunk of example code that prints a sentence then indexs all the characters in the program and finally display's them all in sequential order. But its telling me that the "i" is not initialized here is the code I got:

```
    String sentence = "This is a basic sentence sequence using letters and spaces in unicode!";
    int index = sentence.offsetByCodePoints(0, i);
    int cp = sentence.codePointAt(i);
    System.out.println(index);
    if (Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint(cp)) i += 2;
    else i++;
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Can't see `i` defined in this scope...

Comment: You haven't shown where you've even declared `i`, which makes it very hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the identifier "i" after or before the String sentence like:

```
String sentence = "This is a basic sentence sequence using letters and spaces in unicode!";
int i = 0;
int index = sentence.offsetByCodePoints(0, i);
int cp = sentence.codePointAt(i);
System.out.println(index);
if (Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint(cp)) i += 2;
else i++;
System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

> But its telling me that the "i" is not initialized here is the code I
>   got:

I am assuming `i` is an local variable here. In java Local variables don't get default values. you should initialize them before you use them.

```
public void localVarTest() {
int i;
System.out.println(i);//error cuz you have not initialized local var i
}
```

Initialize  it with default value like :

```
 public void localVarTest() {
    int i=0;
    System.out.println(i);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this however I found another solution to the problem on my own -- sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Got it I had to actually initialize the "i" like so:

```
        String sentence = "This is a basic sentence sequence using letters and spaces in unicode!";
    int i = 0; // Added this part to the code!
    int index = sentence.offsetByCodePoints(0, i);
    int cp = sentence.codePointAt(i);
    System.out.println(index);
    if (Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint(cp)) i += 2;
    else i++;
    System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create variables inside methods you have to assign a value to them:

```
int i = 0;
```

Member variables are initialized automatically with (`0` / `null`)

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that `i` is declared and initialized, also make sure if you have a variable named `i` it's scope is visible to your code.